# Python - calling class from another classes

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to access a variable from another class. In my Model class, I'm trying to access to all the other classes that I've written above. For example, I tried to access to ball class from the model class(it's position). But I get an error when I try to access it.

```
class Ball(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        initialize variables
        self._pos = (x, y)

    def set_position(self, x, y):
        self._pos = (x , y)

    def get_position(self):
        return self._pos


class Model(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._position = Ball().get_position()

    def get_ball_position(self):          
        return self._position
```

.

```
error : __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'
```

Comment: You need to give it arguments, for instance `Ball(4, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create an instance of a ball in your Model class:
`self.ball = Ball(x, y)` **enter coordinates for (x,y)**.
Then access methods from the object you have created. `self.ball.get_position()`

Note that here `self._position = Ball().get_position()` you are attempting to create an instance of a ball and assign it to `self._position`.

What you want to do is create an instance first, and then call the method on the instance.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Sorry i'm new to programming.                             class Model(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ball = Ball(x,y)
      

    def get_ball_position(self):
       
        return ball.get_position()

Comment: Edited, also, see Valentin's comment - you need to give it arguments